# Help with understanding sigma sum-related notation

Tags: summation

My maths book uses this kind of notation for sums (circled in red) but doesn't explain what it means. I don't know what it's called or where to find resources explaining it.

Could someone explain it to me or point out to somewhere where I can read more about it? Just naming it so I can search it would be helpful.

Screenshot of my maths book here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIFeO.png

Comment: The sum is taken over all $n$-tuples $\langle k_1,\ldots,k_n\rangle$ of positive integers such that $k_1+\ldots+k_n=k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation of

$$\sum_{S(k_1, k_2, \ldots)}$$

where $S$ is a statement or equality in terms of $k_1, k_2, \ldots$ means "sum over the values that make the statement true". So in this case, it's "sum over values of $k_1$ to $k_n$ that add up to $k$".

There is an *implicit* restriction on the values here that they are positive (or at least non-negative) integers, although this may not always be true - for example,

$$\sum_{i \in U} a_i$$

is a sum of $a_i$ over all elements $i$ in the set $U$, but it doesn't even state what kind of set $U$ is.

It's also implied that the free variables - the ones we're going to vary in our sum - are the $k_i$ - and that the $k$ is a fixed parameter (this should be clear from the context since $k$ appears in parts of the expression outside of the sigma). As noted in the comments, the more general way to express this might be something like:

$$\sum_{S(k_1, k_2, \ldots ; \theta_1, \theta_2, \ldots)}$$

I'd also note that you *could* expand the expression out into a more explicit representation, but this can make things more, rather than less, complicated. In the case of your particular sum, for example (and replacing the expression inside the sum with a generic term):

$$\sum_{k_1 + k_2 + \ldots + k_n = k} a(k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_n) = \sum_{k_1 = 0}^k \sum_{k_2 = 0}^{k - k_1} \ldots \sum_{k_n = 0}^{k - k_1 - k_2 - \ldots - k_{n-1}} a(k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_n)$$

Isn't that horrendous?

Comment: maybe good to distinguish between inputs to $S$ allowed to vary (our $k_i$) and inputs that are fixed by the context (our $k$). Something like ${S(k_1, k_2, \ldots; \theta_1,\theta_2, \ldots)}$

Comment: Good point, I've added that in plus a bit more.

Comment: Thank you! This was massively helpful!